# I am trying to compile a C/C++ program with OPENMP in linux and I have the following error message

Tags: c++, linux, unix, openmp

The error message is:
error: ‘threadprivate’ ‘ramseries::ErrorWriter::activated_’ directive not in ‘ramseries::ErrorWriter’ definition

I can compile my program in windows but not in linux

Is it not possible to use threadprivate in linux?

This is the line where threadprivate is used:

#pragma omp threadprivate(ErrorParallel::id_branch_,  tdyn::ErrorWriter::activated_, ramseries::ErrorWriter::activated_)

Comment: `threadprivate` is not standard C++ so I guess the answer is no. If you show the code that is using this, then maybe someone will be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: However it is a OPENMP directive. It is accepted in windows but I do not know if it is accepted in linux

Comment: If your compiler supports OpenMP you should be able to compile it. Can you provide a [mre] and more info about the compiler used? Note that `#prama omp`  is a preprocessor directive, so your have to make sure that variables do not have incomplete types.

Comment: Laci 1, thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "make sure that variables do not have incomplete types"?

Comment: An incomplete type is a type that describes an identifier but lacks information needed to determine the size of the identifier (at the preprocessor phase). An incomplete type can be a structure type whose members you have not yet specified, a class template, etc.

Comment: They are integer variables. They are declared as static variables in a header file (error.h) that is include in error.cpp (file where threadprivate directive is used). Moreover, they are initialized before threadprivate directive.

Comment: However, this integer variable belongs to structs

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use the 'threadprivate' directive inside the class definition. The variables where I want to use 'threadprivate' are static members of classes.

For instance,

```
struct ErrorParallel {
  
  static int id_branch_;
  #pragma omp threadprivate(id_branch_)


};
```

In linux version, now I can compile but not in windows, so I have used directives to compile in both SO.

I think I am using different versions of openmp